# F# how to structure a Linq query for master detail data?

Tags: f#

I am using SQLProvider to get data from SQL Server.

My query is shown below. The problem is that it gives me one order record for each line of the order detail. I understand why because if I did this structure in SQL it would give me joined values.

I would like to create a hierarchy though - one order record that has many order details ( even as a tuple ). I just can't get my head around it. I have tried various blocks of code at different levels but it's not working.

```
    let orders = 
        query { 
            for o in ctx.Dbo.Orders do
                for od in o.``dbo.OrderDetails by id`` do
                    select (o , od)
        } |> Seq.map (fun (o,od ) -> o.MapTo<Order>(), od.MapTo<OrderDetail>()) |> Seq.toList
    orders
```

Comment: Probably you should have a look at ```Seq.groupBy``` function to convert the sequence of tuples into a sequence of *Order * OrderDetail seq* pairs.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `groupJoin` query operator is intended for this purpose, but [it doesn't seem to be supported by SQLProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/core/querying.html). Instead, you may have to do something like this:

```
let orders =
    query {
        for o in ctx.Dbo.Orders do
            let ods =
                o.``dbo.OrderDetails by OrderID``
                    |> Seq.toArray
            select (o, ods)
    }
for (o, ods) in orders do
    printfn "Order %A: %A details" o.OrderId ods.Length
```

This results in one row per order, with an array of details for each order, which is what I think you're asking for. Output looks like:

```
Order 10248: 3 details
Order 10249: 2 details
Order 10250: 3 details
Order 10251: 3 details
Order 10252: 3 details
Order 10253: 3 details
Order 10254: 3 details
Order 10255: 4 details
...
```